# Fancy Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

How can I make a `ToC` like the following?

[image]
MWE:

```
‎\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany]{book}‎‎
‎\usepackage{titletoc,xcolor}‎
‎‎
\titlecontents{chapter}% <section-type>
[0pt]% <left>
{}% <above-code>
{\fcolorbox{blue}{blue}{\color{white}\bfseries\chaptername~ \thecontentslabel}}% <numbered-entry-format>
{}% <numberless-entry-format>
{\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}% <filler-page-format>

\begin{document}‎
‎\tableofcontents‎‎
‎
‎\chapter{First Chapter}‎
‎\section{First Section}‎‎‎
‎\section{Second Section}‎‎
‎
‎\chapter{Second Chapter}‎
‎\section{First Section}‎‎
‎\section{Second Section}‎‎
sample
\end{document}‎
```

Comment: -1: This really doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: The visual appearance of the toc is not really appealing -- Are you asking about the technique itself?

Comment: Im agree with Werner and Johannes_B, you don't show us any [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Also I don't know why prefer `titlesec`, `Tikz`is more suitable for what you ask.

Comment: I find the downvotes too harsh at the moment...

Comment: (Our general policy has been to not down-vote beyond -1.  Once it's at -1 then it's clear that there's something wrong with the question and it needs improving.  If it doesn't get improved, it will be closed.  Beyond -1 is therefore unnecessary.  So @ChristianHupfer is right to find that.  There's a meta question on this which I can't find right now.)

Comment: To the OP: You have piled up some questions with good answers, but you did not accept them. This is unsatisfactory... (No, I am not one of the users who gave an answer ;-))

Comment: I've asked a clear question and I need a clear answer; just this.
Moreover, I could write the above code (MWE) and I'd be happy if someone could help me with completing my code until I can get the above image.

Comment: I am not a Tikz-pert, but may be you can use a tikz-matrix. See [this blogposting](http://texblog.net/latex-link-archive/graphics/matrix-table/) to have some ideas. The example is a table, but the table cells look similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: This was a rather good question.  I'm surprised that it has not been asked before.

Comment: @smh: I answered your question with a working solution. Please consider to accept it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A first trial version, requires some more setup for the chapter title line. (I used the traditional `\addcontentsline` way, not `titlesec`)

Don't use too long lines for the chapter lines! I've added just one to show the negative effect of this.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newtcbox{\chapternumberbox}[1][]{%
  colback=blue!50!black,
  colupper={white},
  fontupper={\bfseries\large},
  valign=center,
  size=small,
  nobeforeafter,
  equal height group=chaptertoc,
  #1,
}




\newtcolorbox{chapternamebox}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  valign=center,
  interior style={left color={white!30!blue},right color={white!90!blue}},
  colframe={gray},
  boxrule={1pt},
  colupper={black},
  size=small,
  fontupper={\bfseries\large},
  nobeforeafter,
  equal height group=chaptertoc,
  #1,
}

% A wrapper command
\newcommand{\mychapternamebox}[3][]{%
  \begin{chapternamebox}[#1]
    #2\hfill#3%
  \end{chapternamebox}%
}


\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberbox{\protect\chaptername{} \thechapter}\protect\mychapternamebox[width={9.8cm}]{#1}{\thepage}}%%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}‎‎
\section{Second Section}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
\chapter{Third Chapter with an excessively long title that should be avoided!}‎‎
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** with better spacing

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\makeatletter


\tcbset{%
  chapternumberbox/.style={%
    colframe=black,
    colback={blue!60!white},
    colupper={white},
    fontupper={\bfseries\normalsize},
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    size=small,
    nobeforeafter,
    equal height group=chaptertoc,
    left skip=0pt,
    right skip=0pt,
  },
  chapternamebox/.style={%
    left skip=0pt,
    right skip=0pt,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    valign=center,
    interior style={left color={blue!60!white},right color={blue!15!white}},
    colframe={black},
    boxrule={1pt},
    colupper={black},
    size=small,
    fontupper={\bfseries\normalsize},
    nobeforeafter,
    equal height group=chaptertoc,
  }
}

\newtcolorbox{chapternumberboxinternal}[1][]{%
  chapternumberbox,
  #1
}

\newtcolorbox{chapternamebox}[1][]{%
  chapternamebox,
  #1,
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\chapternumberbox}{O{}m}{%
  \begin{chapternumberboxinternal}[#1,width={\cftchapnumwidth}]%-\kvtcb@left@rule-\kvtcb@right@rule}]
    #2%
  \end{chapternumberboxinternal}%
}



\NewDocumentCommand{\mychapternamebox}{O{}+mm}{%
  \begin{chapternamebox}[#1,width={\dimexpr\tocwidth-\cftchapnumwidth+\marginparsep}]
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\kvtcb@leftupper}@{}@{}p{\dimexpr\tocwidth-\cftchapnumwidth-\@pnumwidth-\kvtcb@leftupper-\marginparsep}@{}@{}R{\dimexpr\@pnumwidth}@{}@{}p{\kvtcb@rightupper}@{}}
      &  #2&#3
    \end{tabular}
  \end{chapternamebox}%
}


\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xprintlen}

\newlength\tocwidth

\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{2.5cm}
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{0pt}



\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\tocwidth}{\linewidth}
}



\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\chapternumberbox{\protect\chaptername\ \thechapter}\protect\mychapternamebox[]{#1}{\thepage}}%%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}‎‎
\section{Second Section}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
\chapter[Theory on Brontosaurs]{Third Chapter with an excessively long title that should be avoided!}‎‎
\end{document}
```

**Update for `vietnam` package**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany]{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{array}




\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\makeatletter


\tcbset{%
  chapternumberbox/.style={%
    colframe=black,
    colback={blue!60!white},
    colupper={white},
    fontupper={\bfseries\normalsize},
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    size=small,
    nobeforeafter,
    equal height group=chaptertoc,
    left skip=0pt,
    right skip=0pt,
  },
  chapternamebox/.style={%
    left skip=0pt,
    right skip=0pt,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    valign=center,
    interior style={left color={blue!60!white},right color={blue!15!white}},
    colframe={black},
    boxrule={1pt},
    colupper={black},
    size=small,
    fontupper={\bfseries\normalsize},
    nobeforeafter,
    equal height group=chaptertoc,
  }
}

\newtcolorbox{chapternumberboxinternal}[1][]{%
  chapternumberbox,
  #1
}

\newtcolorbox{chapternamebox}[1][]{%
  chapternamebox,
  #1,
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\chapternumberbox}{O{}m}{%
  \begin{chapternumberboxinternal}[#1,width={\cftchapnumwidth}]%-\kvtcb@left@rule-\kvtcb@right@rule}]
    #2%
  \end{chapternumberboxinternal}%
}



\NewDocumentCommand{\mychapternamebox}{O{}+mm}{%
  \begin{chapternamebox}[#1,width={\dimexpr\tocwidth-\cftchapnumwidth+\marginparsep}]
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\kvtcb@leftupper}@{}@{}p{\dimexpr\tocwidth-\cftchapnumwidth-\@pnumwidth-\kvtcb@leftupper-\marginparsep}@{}@{}R{\dimexpr\@pnumwidth}@{}@{}p{\kvtcb@rightupper}@{}}
      &  #2&#3
    \end{tabular}
  \end{chapternamebox}%
}


\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xprintlen}

\newlength\tocwidth

\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{2.5cm}
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{0pt}



\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\tocwidth}{\linewidth}
}


\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberbox{\protect\chaptername\ \thechapter}\protect\mychapternamebox[]{#1}{\thepage}}%%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%
}{\typeout{Patch Success}}{\typeout{Patch Failure}}

\makeatother

\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\typeout{Hello}
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
\chapter[Theory on Brontosaurs]{Third Chapter with an excessively long title that should be avoided!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll try to update this with `\l@chapter` instead of modifing `\@chapter`

Comment: @touhami: Thanks. I'll try to update it continously (or more or less continuously ;-))

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I add `\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}`, It doesn't work.

Comment: @toandhsp: I don't speak or can't read Vietnamese

Comment: @toandhsp: See the update at the end please. `vietnam` package must be loaded after the `\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}` statements. Compile three times to get the correct heights

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I used Inder, but the chaptername still is Chapter (In Vietnamese is Chương), not Index (In Vietnamese is Phụ lục). How can I rename in Index?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OPGKUHHcGThz_x9vb9fsSuxbjgEgaHdC/view

Comment: @toandhsp: That's a totally different question... that doesn't belong to this  here, I think