# Incompatible with memoir! Possible modifications?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, tcolorbox

I would like to use the [following fancy toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199794/fancy-table-of-contents) in my memoir document. However, it seems that `\usepackage{tocloft}` is incompatible with memoir. Is it possible that I use it with memoir? What modifications should be made?

I cannot change to `book` since I use fancy chapter styles of memoir.

Comment: From its documentation, `memori` has by default emulated the functionality of `tocloft`, so as my understanding you can directly use macros from that package in `memoir` class. Perhaps you can provide a complete example to show the actual issue.

Comment: The answer can certainly be adapted to `memoir`, but not completely trivially. The `tocloft` commands `\cftchap...` need to be replaced with `\cftchapter...` for use with `memoir`, and the patching of `\@chapter` will need to be adapted to the `memoir` version of `\@chapter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version of the linked answer that uses `memoir`. The main changes are renaming the `tocloft` commands (which are slightly different in `memoir`), and redfining the `memoir` `\@chapter` command rather than just patching it.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany]{memoir}
% Original code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301026/2693
% adapted to work with memoir instead of book+tocloft
\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\makeatletter


\tcbset{%
  chapternumberbox/.style={%
    colframe=black,
    colback={blue!60!white},
    colupper={white},
    fontupper={\bfseries\normalsize},
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    size=small,
    nobeforeafter,
    equal height group=chaptertoc,
    left skip=0pt,
    right skip=0pt,
  },
  chapternamebox/.style={%
    left skip=0pt,
    right skip=0pt,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    valign=center,
    interior style={left color={blue!60!white},right color={blue!15!white}},
    colframe={black},
    boxrule={1pt},
    colupper={black},
    size=small,
    fontupper={\bfseries\normalsize},
    nobeforeafter,
    equal height group=chaptertoc,
  }
}

\newtcolorbox{chapternumberboxinternal}[1][]{%
  chapternumberbox,
  #1
}

\newtcolorbox{chapternamebox}[1][]{%
  chapternamebox,
  #1,
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\chapternumberbox}{O{}m}{%
  \begin{chapternumberboxinternal}[#1,width={\cftchapternumwidth}]%-\kvtcb@left@rule-\kvtcb@right@rule}]
    #2%
  \end{chapternumberboxinternal}%
}



\NewDocumentCommand{\mychapternamebox}{O{}+mm}{%
  \begin{chapternamebox}[#1,width={\dimexpr\tocwidth-\cftchapternumwidth+\marginparsep}]
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\kvtcb@leftupper}@{}@{}p{\dimexpr\tocwidth-\cftchapternumwidth-\@pnumwidth-\kvtcb@leftupper-\marginparsep}@{}@{}R{\dimexpr\@pnumwidth}@{}@{}p{\kvtcb@rightupper}@{}}
      &  #2&#3
    \end{tabular}
  \end{chapternamebox}%
}


\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xprintlen}

\newlength\tocwidth

\renewcommand{\cftchapternumwidth}{2.5cm}
\setlength{\cftchapterindent}{0pt}



\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\tocwidth}{\linewidth}
}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
  \m@mpn@new@chaptrue%
  \m@mpn@new@schapfalse%
  \def\f@rbdy{#2}%
  \ifx\ch@pt@c\@empty % no optional args
    \def\f@rtoc{#2}%
    \def\f@rhdr{#2}%
  \else                  % at least one opt arg
    \let\f@rtoc\ch@pt@c
    \ifx\@empty#1\@empty
      \let\f@rhdr\ch@pt@c
    \else
      \def\f@rhdr{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \m@m@Andfalse
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \if@mainmatter
      \m@m@Andtrue
    \fi
  \fi
  \ifm@m@And
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \fi
  \ifartopt
    \@makechapterhead{#2}%
    \@afterheading
    \chaptermark{\f@rhdr}%
  \else
    \chaptermark{\f@rhdr}
    \insertchapterspace
    \if@twocolumn
      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
    \else
      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
    \fi
    \@afterheading
  \fi
  \@nameuse{chapter@f@rtoc@before@write@hook}%
  \mempreaddchaptertotochook%
  \ifm@m@And
    \ifanappendix
      \addcontentsline{toc}{appendix}{%
        \protect\chapternumberline{\thechapter}\f@rtoc}%
      \memappchapinfo{\thechapter}{\f@rtoc}{\f@rhdr}{#2}%
    \else
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\chapternumberbox{\protect\chaptername\ \thechapter}%
      \protect\mychapternamebox[]{\f@rtoc}{\thepage}}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%
      \memchapinfo{\thechapter}{\f@rtoc}{\f@rhdr}{#2}%
    \fi
  \else
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\chapternumberbox{\protect\chaptername\ \thechapter}
    \protect\mychapternamebox[]{\f@rtoc}{\thepage}}%%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%
    \ifanappendix
      \memappchapinfo{}{\f@rtoc}{\f@rhdr}{#2}%
    \else
      \memchapinfo{}{\f@rtoc}{\f@rhdr}{#2}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \mempostaddchaptertotochook%
  \ifheadnameref\M@gettitle{\f@rhdr}\else\M@gettitle{\f@rtoc}\fi%
  \memendofchapterhook%
}


\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}‎‎
\section{Second Section}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
\chapter[Theory on Brontosaurs]{Third Chapter with an excessively long title that should be avoided!}‎‎
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks Allan. You're a savior.