# How can I combine a Fancy style in my Toc and the use of `\usepackage{hyperref}`?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

So, I have made a fancy style to my Toc (you can find the source code here : [Fancy Table of Contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199794/fancy-table-of-contents/600772#600772)) and when I'm using `\usepackage{hyperref}` the theme of the Toc does not work anymore, but once I delete `\usepackage{hyperref}` it work perfectly. How can I manage between the two ?

Comment: you should learn to make small, but complete examples. I will not wade through a long answer in another post trying to guess what you used from it.

Comment: Add  `\usepackage{hyperref}` before `\begin{document} ` . Change the name of the main file,  or if the TOC does not shows  up, compile again.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74828/161015 on how to use `\PassOptionsToPackage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of curiosity I tested one of examples provided by the answer [Fancy TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301026/161015)

After adding `\usepackage{hyperref}` before `\begin{document}` everything worked fine.

**Remember**

(1) Except for special occasions, `hyperref` should be the last loaded package.

(2) If you already compiled the file,  added `hyperref` and compiled, while keeping the same filename, the table of contents will disappear until you compile again.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\makeatletter


\tcbset{%
    chapternumberbox/.style={%
        colframe=black,
        colback={Gold1},
        colupper={darkgray},
        fontupper={\bfseries\normalsize},
        halign=center,
        valign=center,
        size=small,
        nobeforeafter,
        equal height group=chaptertoc,
        left skip=0pt,
        right skip=0pt,
    },
    chapternamebox/.style={%
        left skip=0pt,
        right skip=0pt,
        enhanced jigsaw,
        valign=center,
        interior style={left color={Gold2!70},right color={Gold3!15!white}},
        colframe={black},
        boxrule={1pt},
        colupper={black},
        size=small,
        fontupper={\bfseries\normalsize},
        nobeforeafter,
        equal height group=chaptertoc,
    }
}

\newtcolorbox{chapternumberboxinternal}[1][]{%
    chapternumberbox,
    #1
}

\newtcolorbox{chapternamebox}[1][]{%
    chapternamebox,
    #1,
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\chapternumberbox}{O{}m}{%
    \begin{chapternumberboxinternal}[#1,width={\cftchapnumwidth}]%-\kvtcb@left@rule-\kvtcb@right@rule}]
        #2%
    \end{chapternumberboxinternal}%
}



\NewDocumentCommand{\mychapternamebox}{O{}+mm}{%
    \begin{chapternamebox}[#1,width={\dimexpr\tocwidth-\cftchapnumwidth+\marginparsep}]
        \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\kvtcb@leftupper}@{}@{}p{\dimexpr\tocwidth-\cftchapnumwidth-\@pnumwidth-\kvtcb@leftupper-\marginparsep}@{}@{}R{\dimexpr\@pnumwidth}@{}@{}p{\kvtcb@rightupper}@{}}
            &  #2&#3
        \end{tabular}
    \end{chapternamebox}%
}


\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xprintlen}

\newlength\tocwidth
%
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{2.5cm}
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{0pt}


%
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \setlength{\tocwidth}{\linewidth}
}

%

\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
    {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\chapternumberbox{\protect\chaptername\ \thechapter}\protect\mychapternamebox[]{#1}{\thepage}}%%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \section{First Section}
    \section{Second Section}
    \chapter{Second Chapter}
    \section{First Section}
    \section{Second Section}
    \chapter[Theory on Brontosaurs]{Third Chapter with an excessively long title that should be avoided!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much I really appreciate it

Comment: Another question please, this package `\usepackage[x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}` does not work for me, any idea why ?

Comment: @TTT Did you compile my answer, as it is?

Comment: Yeah, you're code is working perfectly but just I'm asking if there is any packages that prevent this one from working perfectly

Comment: @TTT  Probably another package had already loaded the xcolor package without options.
 
  For testing use only `\usepackage{xcolor}` (or do not load it at all )  and change the fancy names of colors to simple blue, red, etc. –  Putting  `\listfiles` before the `\documentclass` will list all packages loaded in the log file.